# Virtual Attribute

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

I've defined a virtual attribute in model

```
public $Pictures;
    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['Pictures'], 'safe'],

        ]
    }
    public function getPictures(){
        $pics="1.jpg";
        return $pics;
    }
```

and i got data in controller:

```
$estates = Estates::find()->asArray()->all();
```

in view:

```
print_r($estates)
```

but just this attribute can't be shown in view

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define it on declaration or in rules.

```
$Pictures = '1.jpg';
```

Or in rules

```
[['Pictures'], 'default', 'value' => '1.jpg'],
```

Or even after find

```
public function afterFind() 
{
    $this->Pictures = '1.jpg';

    return parent:: afterFind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare that the new virtual  attributes  is safe this can be done with an explicit declaration in model validation's rule  eg:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       [['Pictures',], 'safe'],
    ];
 }
```

or implicitally as suggested  by @Ripper assigning a validation rule  eg:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['Pictures',], 'string', 'max' => 32],
    ];
 }
```